# ListBox WPF- VirtualizingStackPanel with two rows, like wrappanel

Tags: wpf, row, stackpanel, virtualizingstackpanel

My listBox:

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Name="lst" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,-23">
...
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

I need the same, but with VirtualizingStackPanel. If i change WrapPanel with VirtualizingStackPanel, items are showing only in a row while before i had many rows. 
I need help.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set your `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `VirtualStackPanel`, and set the `Orientation` to `Vertical`.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```